# Creating Custom DataType for GoogleFit

Tags: android, google-fit, custom-data-type

I've been trying to create a custom data type for a google fit application and I have been running into a few errors. Originally ConfigApi.createCustomDataType was getting the following error

"non-static method 'createCustomDataType (com.google.android.gms.common.api.GoolgeApiClient, com.google.android.gms.fitness.request.DataTypeCreateRequest)cannot be referenced from a static context"

So I instantiated the ConfigApi to bypass that error and then I got the following error when I ran the application:

java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke interface method 'void com.google.android.gms.common.api.PendingResult.setResultCallback(com.google.android.gms.common.api.ResultCallback)' on a null object reference

That error is coming on this line: pendingResult.setResultCallback

I'm hoping someone can help me out with what I doing wrong before I start to make a bigger mess than I already have. Below is the code I am working with:

```
    // build a request to create a new data type
    DataTypeCreateRequest request = new DataTypeCreateRequest.Builder()
            .setName(myPackageName)
            .addField("custom", Field.FORMAT_INT32)
            .build();

    // invoke the CONFIG API with (Google API client object and create data type request)

    // instantiating ConfigApi due to the following error:
    // non-static method createCustomDataType cannot be referenced from a static context 

    ConfigApi configApi = new ConfigApi() {
        @Override
        public PendingResult<DataTypeResult> createCustomDataType(GoogleApiClient googleApiClient, DataTypeCreateRequest dataTypeCreateRequest) {
            return null;
        }

        @Override
        public PendingResult<DataTypeResult> readDataType(GoogleApiClient googleApiClient, String s) {
            return null;
        }

        @Override
        public PendingResult<Status> disableFit(GoogleApiClient googleApiClient) {
            return null;
        }
    };

    PendingResult<DataTypeResult> pendingResult =
            configApi.createCustomDataType(mClient, request);
    /** 
      * ConfigApi.createCustomDataType was getting the following error:
      * non-static method 'createCustomDataType 
      * (com.google.android.gms.common.api.GoolgeApiClient,
      * com.google.android.gms.fitness.request.DataTypeCreateRequest)
      * cannot be referenced from a static context
      */

    // 3. Check the result asynchronously
    // (The result may not be immediately available)
    pendingResult.setResultCallback(
            new ResultCallback<DataTypeResult>() {
                @Override
                public void onResult(DataTypeResult dataTypeResult) {

                    if (dataTypeResult.getStatus().isSuccess()){
                        DataType customType = dataTypeResult.getDataType();
                        // Use this custon data type to insert data in your app
                        onDataTypeAvailable(customType);
                    }

                    // Retrieve the created data type
                    // Use this custom data type to insert data in your app
                    // (see other examples)

                }
            }
    );
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When you create your GoogleApiClient, make sure to add the config API:

```
 GoogleApiClient client = new GoogleApiClient.Builder()
     .addApi(Fitness.CONFIG_API)
     ...
     .build();
```

Comment: Thank you I didn't realize I could add multiple APIs to the GoogleApiClient

Answer (score 0):

You probably want to use Fitness.ConfigApi instead of creating your own implementation of ConfigApi.

Comment: Thanks, so I changed it to Fitness.ConfigApi and now I get an error for that line stating Appropriate Api was not requested.

Answer (score 0):

To expand on Guga's first answer (a bit late, but just in case others have the same question):

I had the exact same problem. Turns out that the example code from the overview (which you probably found [here](https://developers.google.com/fit/android/data-types), as I did) might not be entirely correct. In an example from Google's ConfigApi documentation ([here](https://developers.google.com/android/reference/com/google/android/gms/fitness/ConfigApi)), a similar method, `readDataType()`, is called a different way (although the incorrect call is repeated once there too).

Applying the example to `createCustomDataType()`, the call should be as follows:

```
PendingResult pendingResult = Fitness.ConfigApi.createCustomDataType(mClient, request);
```

(And of course, don't forget to add the correct API to your client.)